# pymol isn't launching from the terminal

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, pymol

so i installed pymol using anaconda after creating an env37 environment. and everytime i try launching pymol from the terminal it throws the following error:

"This Executable Build integrates and extends Open-Source PyMOL.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

has anyone come across such an issue?

Comment: `tar xvf PyMOL-2.5.2_293-Linux-x86_64-py37.tar.bz2 && cd pymol/ && ./pymol` : The pymol GUI opens OK ..... no issues. (This version requires no python, i.e. python3.7 is included in the app.)

Comment: thanks. works for me.
can you tell how can i open pymol regardless which directory i am in?

Comment: My example → As root, or with sudo → `# cd /usr/local/bin/ && ln -s /home/knudfl/Downloads/pymol/bin/pymol` .... Then the executable 'pymol' is i a "system PATH"-